# Notify the View after async Task is completed in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a view and I send data through ajax to an action in MVC. I want to be notified in the view only when the task is done. The problem I encounter is whether I'm notified before or if i wait untill the the task is done my view is blocked. Here it is un example of what i do:

```
function UploadFile(file) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Upload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: file,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);

        }
    });
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(httpPostedFileBase file)
{
        NewFile service = new NewFile((long)Session["UserId"]);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>service.UploadFile(file));
        thread.Start();
        return Json("File Uploaded", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


    public async Task<string> UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) // returns the file Id in Google Drive
    {
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File uploadedFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        try
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // Check for credentials
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = Service;
                // Uploads the file to the server in "~/GoogleDriveFiles" folder.
                /*string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"),*/ // TODO Doesn't work with Unit testing. Must be written manual for testing
                //Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                //file.SaveAs(path);
                // Save the metadata of the file
                var FileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName),
                    MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.FileName),
                    Parents = new List<string>
                    {
                       GetReposFolderId()
                    }
                };
                // Create a request for upload
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                file.InputStream.Close();
                // Create a stream using the file filepath and filling the request. Then upload.
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(file.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    request = service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    await request.UploadAsync();//TODO Tuka bavi i ne mozesh da browswash prez papkite dokato ne go kachi na servara
                }
                uploadedFile = request.ResponseBody;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorEngine.RuntimeExceptions runtimeExceptions = new ErrorEngine.RuntimeExceptions();
            runtimeExceptions.ManageException(ex, this);
            return ex.ToString();
        }
        return uploadedFile.Id;
    }
```

I'm not very experienced with MVC and codding in general as you might thought. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: You should ***never*** call `new Thread(...)`  unless you are writing a custom thread scheduler. You should be using `Task.Run(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is you cant ....

if you do not want to wait for the processing... then it will never know...

**UNLESS**

either, you use a **poller** and ask every x time or use a two way comms.... which is quite a bit of coding but you could look at **SingalR**, then you could issue a msg and all listens can receive.

so the easiest.... for you... is to upload the file as one request and make that wait for the response.

Uploading and the action as to what to do can be separated, that's what many sites do.. you can use js, to have a progress bar as to how far it is with uploading the file to the server..but processing o the server unless you wait, there would be no way other than what i said above or variations there of.

options are **poller** or **socket base tech**, or **simply wait** for upload to and processing to complete.

The uploading and the processing can be separate calls with different responce and this is what most sites do...

Comment: Thank you for your answere! But if i upload the file as one request and wait for the reponse the view will be blocked right?

Comment: like i said without complicating it.... make the upload an action and then the submit an action where the submit interacts on the already uploaded file... so the submit is only about second action. so user interaction, so they want to give an image... first they upload, so as soon as they choose a file it starts the upload, then when that is done.... which you can give them a progress bar, then once it uploaded you can show them ... then they can click save/submit, which then uses the already uploaded file. obviously you need to save the file in temp locations first then when save..get and do

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've need it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Upload(httpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try {
        NewFile service = new NewFile((long)Session["UserId"]);
        await Task.Run(() => service.UploadFile(file));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    return Json("File Uploaded", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Your code would not compile. you have no return statement outside of the await. Also, using a Task.Run to call `new Thread(...).Start()` is kinda useless.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean about the Task.Run but that won't change that I get no notification in my View when the  Thread or the Task is completed. I trigger my success function in the ajax request before the task is completed. What I need is to get notification AFTER the Task is completed without blocking the view during the process.

Comment: Julian - I've edited my answer but without seeing your complete set up I'm making several assumptions, mainly that your file upload task is synchronous and working as a separate service. If that's the case then wrapping it inside Task.Run should work and get you notified when finished.

Comment: Keith - When I put it in  await Task. Run ()the Veiw is blocked untill the file is uploaded. If the file is big it can take quite a long time. If i put it without  await the view is not blocked, the file is uploaded in background but i get no notification when the file is uploaded because the success function in the ajax request is triggered before the upload is completed. I want to get notification when the upload is completed without blocking the view.

Comment: Julian - Can post the signature of your UploadFile service? I want to find out if it is: public void UploadFile(File SomeFile) or public Task UploadFile(File SomeFile)

Comment: Keith - the upload function is public async Task UploadFile(someFile). Is that what you need?